# Filter out props from null value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a provider that sends data via props. It sends about 4-5 null values before the props contain the data I need ("mailto" mailadress). Since the null data comes BEFORE the mail adress, the props is not usable as it will not have the data I need. So somehow I need to structure my code to update when I get the mailadress or fitler out the null values. The props is a string value.

Currently I have tried:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    url: "",
    loading: false
  };
}

public componentDidMount(): void {
  let urls = "";
  if (this.props.url != null && undefined)
    if (this.props.url.length > 0) {
      urls = this.props.url;
    }

  this.setState({
    url: this.state.url + urls
  });
  console.log(this.state.url);
}

public render(): React.ReactElement<ImyProps> {
  var iconStyle = {
    fontSize: ``,
    display: "inline-block",
    color: " #ff0033"
  };

  const { loading, url } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(this.state.url)}

      <Icon
        style={iconStyle}
        iconName="Lightbulb"
        className="ms-IconExample"
      />

      {this.state.loading && this.state.url && (
        <a href={this.props.url}>
          <p>Test. {this.props.url}</p>
        </a>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I have a componedDitMount hook (tried it without that as well) where I try to filter out the null values, it does not work. Seems like the props with the value come later in the lifecycle. Cant do array functions on the props as well as its a single string.

Comment: `if(this.props.url != null && undefined)` is not the `if` statement you're looking for (you're not actually checking if `this.props.url` is `undefined` you're checking if `undefined` has a `true` value, which it does not). `if(!this.props.url)` should be good enough for what you're doing.

Comment: this is wrong `if(this.props.url != null && undefined)`  a simple `if(this.props.url != null)` is enough as `!=null` operator handles both `null` and `undefined` values

Comment: @Arte2 try this `if(!this.props.url)`

Comment: `componentDidMount` lifecycle is called only **once** when component is mounted to the DOM.

Comment: Check you this article about derived state https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you said that *"It sends about 4-5 null values before the props contain the data I need"*: this means that your Component will not have the prop you need the first time it's rendered.
Why this matter? Because you used `componentDidMount()`, which is called only when the Component is mounted for the first time; in your case, because of what you said, `componentDidMount()` will be run when `this.props.url` is equal to `null`.

Said that, as some of the users said in the comment, the `IF` statement is also wrong.

Anyways, you should write something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.url) {
        // Here you have this.props.url with some value    
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't actually need to implement `componentDidMount` if you are 100% sure that the first the Component is rendered, its props do not contain the data you need.

I haven't written the code inside the `IF` statement because I'm not sure if `this.props.url` should be an array of strings, or it should be just a string.